# Custom tab item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I need to add a custom tab item into my TabbedPage. That shouldn't be a page but an overlay view. It is "More" item for the bottom menu opening a more items menu over the currently shown page.
So far I found the following solution:

```
 protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
 {
     base.OnCurrentPageChanged();

     if (this.isInitialized)
     {
         if (CurrentPage.Title == "More")
         {
             CurrentPage = this.lastSelectedPage;
         }
     }

     this.lastSelectedPage = CurrentPage;
 }
```

It's enough to prevent opening the corresponding fake page. After this I need to show an overlay view and have no item how to do it from the tabbed page.
Another solution I'm working out now is to write a custom renderer for my tabbed page and manage all the custom work there. The question in this case is how to show my custom view over the existing content. I tried `AddView` (iOS) in the renderer but getting runtime exception.

```
public override void ItemSelected(UITabBar tabbar, UITabBarItem item)
{
    base.ItemSelected(tabbar, item);

    var view = new UILabel()
    {
        Text = "Test"
    };

    View.Add(view);
}
```

Comment: I assume that you realize a "More" tab will be created for you automatically when there are more than five tabs? Are you saying that you require more than what the default implementation does?

Comment: @KeithRome oh... thanks for reminding this. I think I can use the default implementation with the only exception I will need to customize the "More" screen appearance.